# redefining base class method in derived class

Tags: c++

I have base class name foo_base

```
class foo_base {

    foo_base(){};
    ~foo_base(){};

    virtual int counter(){};
};

class foo_derived : public foo_base{

    foo_derived(){};
    ~foo_derived(){};

    int counter() {   int temp = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 10;)
                temp += i;
            return temp;
            }
};


int main(){

int numbers  = 0;

foo_base * foo_base_ptr;
foo_base_ptr = new foo_derived();

numbers = foo_base_ptr->counter();   /*error */


delete foo_base_ptr;

return 0;
}
```

when I try to compile program I got this error:

```
error C4716: 'foo_base::counter' : must return a value
```

I want define counter() in the foo_drived. how can I do that?
Is there any way to redefine foo_base method in the foo_derived class?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? If you don't want an implementation of `counter()` in `foo_base` make it a pure virtual function: `virtual int counter() = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Inside

```
class foo_base {

    foo_base(){};
    ~foo_base(){};

    virtual int counter(){};
};
```

You define a function for `counter` that does not return an integer. Change to (Base Class will return 0, derived will override):

```
class foo_base {

    foo_base(){};
    ~foo_base(){};

    virtual int counter(){return 0;};
};
```

And it should compile

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the counter() function in the base class return an int. You defined the return type of the function, yet did not provide a proper definition of the function. That should fix *that* issue, but you have others as well.

When you define classes, you cannot have the destrcutors be marked as private. In C++, unlike Java, variables & functions are 'private' by default. You need to explicitly mark members as public in order to make them public.

To fix your first issue:

```
`virtual int counter(){ return 0 }; //It doesn't have to return 0, just an int. Used this for demo sake'
```

To fix your second issue:

```
class foo_base {
public: // This will make everything below public, so only do this if your goal is to have everything marked as public (i.e. use private where necessary)
    foo_base(){};
    ~foo_base(){};

    virtual int counter(){};
};

class foo_derived : public foo_base{
public:
    foo_derived(){};
    ~foo_derived(){};

    int counter() {   int temp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10;)
            temp += i;
        return temp;
        }
};
```

As commented in the code, use public where necessary. But, it doesn't make sense to mark your constructor as private in this scenario (based on the code presented). Again, that is your choice. The destructor, however, must be marked as public in order for inheritance to work.

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

1. Your constructors are private, make them public if you want to derive and use.
2. In your for loop, increment `i`, right now its infinite loop
3. Not sure of your compiler but most compilers do not throw errors if the control reaches at the end of the function without a return statement, it displays a warning. However, if you see an error, you should `return 0` or something to make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement your `counter()` function for the `foo_base` class in `foo_derived`. What you probably want is to make is either (1) make the base class abstract or (2) provide a implementation in `foo_base` for `counter()`.

However, if you define the `counter()` not as pure virtual (i.e. `virtual int counter() = 0;`, the compiler will complain, because you need an implementation.
One option would be to replace `virtual int counter(){};` with `virtual int counter(){ return 0; };`.